# Definitions and examples of large set and large subset

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My question is to find a large subset $A$ of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$ with the property that if $x$ and $y$ are in $A$, then their average, $\frac{x + y}{2}$, is **not** in $A$.

I could understand the question but I don't know what "a large subset of the integers $\mathbb{Z}$" means. I have looked up the meaning of large set on wikipedia, but there are three different definitions, and I'm confused which one should I use. Could someone please gives the definitions of large set and large subset for this question? It would be better if some examples can be provided. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you asked the author of that question?

Comment: No, it's from a mathematics competition that a friend of mine has just participated. He doesn't know the answer neither so he sends this question to me

Answer (score 0):

I think by "a large set" they mean an infinite one so that you cant just take A = {1,2} and get a trivial answer. Here is an example:

Try taking A to be the set of integers $2^n$ for all positive integers n.

If x and y are in A, then we can write $x = 2^a$ and $y = 2^b$ with $b>a$ without loss of generality.

Then we can work out $(x+y)/2$:

$$\frac{2^a + 2^b}{2} = 2^{a-1}({1+2^{b-a}})$$

and this is clearly not an integer power of 2, so is not in the set A.